# UIScrollView strategies for horizontal and vertical scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

Situation: I have a toolbar of sorts (not a UIToolbar, just a custom UIView) that sits at the top of my view. This toolbar has a number of buttons. Immediately below it, I have a scrollview with a form. When a button on the toolbar is tapped, the corresponding form should be animated onto the screen from the right or the left, depending on which button is tapped. I don't want the toolbar to move on this. However, I do want the toolbar to scroll up when the user scrolls up or down on the scroll view. The way I've accomplished it now is in the scrollViewDidScroll delegate method (note I only allow horizontal scrolling if it's from pressing a button on the toolbar):

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.x != 0 && _shouldScrollHorizontally == NO)
    {
        CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
        offset.x = 0;
        scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
    }

    CGRect buttonFrame = [_buttons frame];

    buttonFrame.origin.y = -scrollView.contentOffset.y + 10;

    [_buttons setFrame:buttonFrame];
}
```

However, I'm concerned that this is inefficient and will cause some latency. I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve.

At the end of the day, I want the toolbar to remain stationary if the scrollview is scrolled horizontally, but to move with the scrollview if the scrollview is scrolled vertically.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: you mean you want a graphics like old pulse, or postpiks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since horizontal 'scrolling' is only allowed when a button is tapped, then set the `UIScrollView` `contentSize` width to the width of the screen and its height as appropriate. For 'scrolling' horizontally on button taps, just animate the moving of a view horizontally.

The view hierarchy would be something like an `outerView` that is the width and height of what you are setting your `UIScrollView contentSize` to currently. Your scroll view is a subview of the `outerView` and the toolbar is a subview of the scroll view.

To animate the horizontal movement, it is typically easiest to change the `outerView.center`   and the `toolbarView.center`, something like:

> ```
> CGPoint newCenterPoint;
> CGPoint newToolbarCenterPoint;
>
> CGPoint centerPoint1 = // set center as appropriate
> CGPoint centerPoint2 = // set center as appropriate
> CGPoint centerPoint3 = // set center as appropriate
>
> CGPoint toolbarCenter1 = // set center as appropriate
> CGPoint toolbarCenter2 = // set center as appropriate
> CGPoint toolbarCenter3 = // set center as appropriate
>
> if (buttonTapped == button1) {
>     newCenterPoint = centerPoint1;
>     newToolbarCenterPoint = toolbarCenter1;
> } else if (buttonTapped == button2){
>     newCenterPoint = centerPoint2;
>     newToolbarCenterPoint = toolbarCenter2;
> } else if (buttonTapped == button3){
>     newCenterPoint = centerPoint3;
>     newToolbarCenterPoint = toolbarCenter3;
> }
> [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
>     outerView.center = newCenterPoint;
>     toolbarView.center = newToolbarCenterPoint;
> }];
> ```